# Graphic corruption after exiting my wp7 game

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I am making a videogame in xna for wp7 and I have a weird problem.

It turns out that whenever my game loses focus, for example:

- open the web browser from my game
- open marketplace from the game
- close the game

when something of that happens the screen gets full of graphical artifacts and the device becomes unusable unless you go back to the game.

I discovered that if you maintain pressed the back button until the "background apps" is showed it works fine again. But  my game won't pass the QA if this problem persists.

I've tried to comment the update and draw methods of my game but it still happens!! :S

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Does the problem occur on a physical device, or in the emulator? In the latter case, it's most likely an issue with your hardware/SDK installation.

Comment: it occurs on a physical device (nokia lumia 710). On the emulator works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well I fixed it.

It turns out that in a custom texture class, (I don't know why) there was code to create a Texture2D object with custom size. It worked fine (the game runs perfectly) but there is something that the device doesn't like and it corrupted the backbuffer.

What I've done is delete that code and instantiate the Textures always in their original sizes. Now it works great and no artifacts have been found :D